# JAVA | Error al hacer EQUAL de 2 ARRAYS

Tags: java

Me da error al comparar. ¿Qué sucede?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[2];
        array1[0] = 11;
        array1[1] = 4;
        int[] array2 = {11, 4};

        if (Arrays.equals(array1, array2)){
            System.out.println("Iguales.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Diferentes.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da al momento de comparar? El resultado en pantalla será: `Iguales`, no le veo ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que el método equals es el comparador de objetos, ya que los arrays en este caso son colecciones de datos de tipo primitivo (int) deben de compararse con el operador `==` entonces en este orden de ideas la solución sería la simple

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[2];
        array1[0] = 11;
        array1[1] = 4;
        int[] array2 = {11, 4};

        if (array1 ==array2){
            System.out.println("Iguales.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Diferentes.");
        }
    }
}
```

ahora si lo que quieres es implementar la función equals, es necesario recurrir a los wrappers como Integer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array1 = new Integer[2];
        array1[0] = 11;
        array1[1] = 4;
        Integer[] array2 = {11, 4};

        if (Arrays.equals(array1, array2)){
            System.out.println("Iguales.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Diferentes.");
        }
    }
}
```

saludos

Comment: La pregunta del OP está bien y no hay ningún error de comparación. Más bien, esta línea: `array1 ==array2` lo que se hace es comparar direcciones de memoria de ambos punteros implicitos, por ende, la condición no dará como resultado un `false`, a excepción, que el puntero `array1` apunte a lo mismo que `array2`.